# Javascript array index object

Tags: javascript

I have an array:

```
var assArray = {};
assArray["VeryImportantData1"]="VeryImportant"; 
assArray["VeryImportantDataTest"]="VeryImportant"; 
assArray["Very"]="VeryImportant"; 
assArray["Vey"]="VeryImportant"; 
assArray["Test"]="VeryImportant"; 
assArray["Dumdum"]="VeryImportant";
```

How do I get the index of every element in this array in Javascript?

Comment: `Object.keys(assArray)`?

Answer (score 1):

First of all, a bit of terminology: That is not an array, it is an object.

Now that that's out of the way, I can't tell for certain what you're asking for. Are you looking for this, perhaps?:

```
for( var i in assArray) {
    alert(i+": "+assArray[i]);
    // bad example, do something useful here
}
```

Comment: You may also want to filter out properties from prototypes using `assArray.hasOwnProperty(i)`

Comment: @steff There shouldn't be any *if* the environment is sane.

Answer (score 1):

You can use something like:

```
var keys = Object.keys(assArray);

for(var index = 0; index < keys.length; index++)
{
    var key = keys[index];

    // Do something with the index and key...
    alert(key + ' has an index of: ' + index);
}
```

Reference for `Object.keys(obj)`

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys

> Object.keys returns an array whose elements are strings corresponding
>   to the enumerable properties found directly upon object. The ordering
>   of the properties is the same as that given by looping over the
>   properties of the object manually.

Comment: If you can use `Object.keys()` you can probably also use `forEach()` :)

Comment: Yeah, thought about that...not sure why I chose index++ in the end!

Answer (score 0):

Basically what you have here is a set of "key" "value" pairs. You don't have an array with 0...n  indexes. To access the data structure you'll need to use your keys ("VeryImportantData1", "VeryImportantDataTest", etc.).

Simple examples of how to access the key/values:

alert(assArray['Dumdum']); //This will alert "VeryImportant"

console.log(assArray['Vey']); //This will log "VeryImportant"

Answer (score 0):

You could use something like:

```
function getKeyListFor(obj, term, sortOpt) {
    var keys=[];
    for (var k in obj) {
        if (obj[k] === term) keys.push(k);
    }
    if (keys.length) {
        if (sortOpt) keys.sort();
        return keys;
    }
    else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

Note: The sort-argument would be optional. (Since keys of associative arrays (objects) are stored internally as hashes, they are returned in apparently random order else. Mind that Array.sort() without any sorting function as an argument always performs a string comparison in incrementing order. As any value-type may be converted to a meaningful string representation, this is also a sane default.)

```
// Usage example
var fruitColors = {
    'banana': 'yellow',
    'apple': 'red',
    'orange': 'orange',
    'strawberry': 'red'
}
var redList = getKeyListFor( fruitColors, 'red', true );
// returns ['apple', 'strawberry']
var blueList = getKeyListFor( fruitColors, 'blue' );
// returns null
if (blueList) {
    // delete all blue entries
    for (var i=0; i<blueList.length; i++) {
        var key = blueList[i];
        delete fruitColors[key];
    }
}
```